# sublhandler.app - opens, but doesn't open sublime text

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext

I've installed [subl handler](https://github.com/asuth/subl-handler), and I'm trying to test it with the recommended:

```
open 'subl://open/?url=file:///etc/hosts'
```

Running this in terminal opens the SublHandler.app itself, but then does nothing - it doesn't open sublime text, let alone the file specified.

In SublHandler prefs, I have the "path to subl" set to `/usr/local/bin/subl`. If I run `/usr/local/bin/subl` in my terminal, it opens sublime text.

Any ideas as to why SublHandler isn't working?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the latest binary from asuth is not working correctly on Maverics. Try my fork here https://github.com/grych/subl-handler - it is working on 10.9.1.

Comment: Hmm. Works great in Safari but it doesn't seem to open in chrome for me.

Comment: Thanks ! Works great on OSX 10.11 with Chrome !